# First time images can see but now it wont(added images statically)

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

In my `home.blade.php` page I have some authorization codes and in another `<div>` I placed image tag to display images, it worked fine but now I cannot see those images.

home.blade.php

```
<div class="row pt-5">
  <div class="col-4">
     <img src="images/aa.jpg" alt="" class="w-100">
  </div>

<div class="col-4">
     <img src="images/bb.jpg" alt="" class="w-100">
 </div>

 <div class="col-4">
     <img src="images/cc.jpg" alt="" class="w-100">
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the error I get

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

also show these messages

> Download the Vue Devtools extension for a better development experience:
>
> You are running Vue in development mode.
>     Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.

Comment: In which folder the images are located? Add path of that folder to link the images.

Comment: no there is no problem. anyway images folder inside the public.                                   and I also show an image in the same way and it works .                                              <div class="col-3 p-5">
           <img src="/images/dc.jpg" height="135" width="125" class="rounded-circle" alt="">
       </div>

Comment: what is the route that you access this view. Are these images are in the "images" folder of the same path? (maybe you should replace images/aa.jpg with /images/aa.jpg?)

Comment: thank you dude it works now when I use '/' infront of images.. eventhough it had worked perfectly without the front slash.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but maybe you just need to use the absolute path?

```html
<div class="row pt-5">
  <div class="col-4">
     <img src="/images/aa.jpg" alt="" class="w-100">
  </div>

<div class="col-4">
     <img src="/images/bb.jpg" alt="" class="w-100">
 </div>

 <div class="col-4">
     <img src="/images/cc.jpg" alt="" class="w-100">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you dude it works now when I use '/' infront of images.. eventhough it had worked perfectly without the front slash.